# Flurry Crash Analytics not reporting crashes

Tags: ios, analytics, crash-reports, flurry

I have enabled Flurry crash analytics in my app. My app crashes but it is not reported under the Errors section of Flurry Dashboard , but can be seen as exception logs under the "errors" option of Technical section.

How long will it take to report ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Flurry, I dont know if the behavior is sent straightaway. In the case of flurry analytics, is not straightaway and you have to wait sometime. My questions now are : have you configured correctly the application with your flurry key? does the application ask you to send the report once it has happened and you reopen the app? Sometimes, and it happens in all the frameworks like crashlytics, if the app doesnt ask you to send the report, it can mean a hardware problem has happened (external to the app) and it wont be sent to the backend. Take a look in all the steps.

Comment: Yes , The key entered is perfectly fine. And no , I do not receive any dialogue asking me to send the report.

All I have done is enabled [FLurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];

in my app delegate before calling [Flurry startSession:key]; and it seems to be correct.

Comment: So for my understanding, wait sometime to see whats going on, if it doesnt work it can be a different problem, Flurry doesnt work OTA, you have to wait to have your online profile updated, just wait a little while to see what happens, because sometimes I noticed a period between a couple of hours or more to get some results

Comment: Will it take so much of time to report every crash or is it taking time since its the first time ?

Comment: It really depends how they update the information. Sometimes it can take time, what is a problem if you need the information asap! I would recommend you in this case, to use crashlytics; most of the time I use flurry for analytics or it really depends on the client requirements, but for crash reports, Im always using crashlytics now, or an internal tool I developed (just for some clients).